# What is the idiomatic way to do a static initializer in Clojure without having it run on compilation?

Tags: clojure, static-initialization

I want to do a static initializer in Clojure similar to what you can do in Java.

```
public class Test {

    static{
        System.out.println("Static");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Static main");
    }
}
```

Now I'm aware you could do something like:

```
(ns myns)

(defn my-func [] (println "my-func called"))

(my-func)
```

But that will be run at compilation, which I'd like to avoid.

What I could do it call it from a static initializer in a Java class, and then switch AOT compilation off, but that doesn't seem idiomatic.

My question is: **What is the idiomatic way to do a static initializer in Clojure without having it run on compilation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've typically seen namespace resources initialized at runtime but not compile time is using a delay:

```
(defn init-resource [] ...)

(def my-resource (delay (init-resource)))

(defn do-something []
  (let [r @my-resource] ...))
```

This is not exactly what you're looking for, as `my-resource` is not initialized until `do-something` is invoked, which might be well after the namespace is loaded.

If it's a hard requirement that the initialization is done when the namespace is loaded, you could wrap the initialization code in some code that checks the `clojure.core/*compile-files*` flag to see if code is being compiled. However, I wouldn't exactly call this idiomatic:

```
(defn init-resource [] ...)

(defmacro do-runtime [& body]
  `(when-not *compile-files* ~@body))

(def my-resource (do-runtime (init-resource)))

(defn do-something []
  (let [r my-resource] ...))
```